# Can we still create multiple apps in nx?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I worked a little bit with NX in the past. I'm trying to create 2 applications: the frontend and the admin. My recollection is that you would have a folder called **/apps** where all the applications would be and **/libs** where the libraries would be. You could

Now on the nx website, you can create your repo through **package-based repo**, **integrated repo**, and **standalone**. None of those methods generate a folder called **/apps**.

When I run `npx create-nx-workspace@latest myorg --preset=ts`, it's not asking me for the **application name**.

[Everywhere I read or watch the videos posted on their website](https://nx.dev/getting-started/integrated-repo-tutorial), they talk about libraries. Are there still apps or everything is libraries now?

I just bought on Udemy a [course that was updated in July 2022](https://www.udemy.com/course/monorepos-a-beginners-guide/?ranMID=39197&ranEAID=%2FjZHTpnCvx8&ranSiteID=_jZHTpnCvx8-MiinDGSnN0NEB6URldVA8Q&LSNPUBID=%2FjZHTpnCvx8&utm_source=aff-campaign&utm_medium=udemyads), but the course is so different from what's in the website.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your workspace using

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest myorg --preset=ts
```

you are telling Nx to setup a workspace where all projects will live under the `./packages` directory (that is the `--preset=ts` layout).

If you'd like to have separate `apps` and `libs` directories. You can use the `--preset=apps` . You can also run the `create-nx-workspace` command without passing a preset, this will prompt you what you are looking for with descriptive information about every option available.

```
npx create-nx-workspace@latest myorg
```

And example of this setup is available in the [Node tutorial docs](https://nx.dev/getting-started/node-tutorial).

Bonus:

Nx has been on active development lately. Nx v15.3 introduced standalone apps projects, where you can leverage Nx capabilities in a non-monorepo setup. Read about standalone presets in the [react standalone tutorial docs](https://nx.dev/getting-started/react-standalone-tutorial). This is another layout option for your Nx workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly create an empty repo with this command. Then run

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:app appName
```

To generate another application.

You can find more info on angular package root documentation: https://nx.dev/packages/angular For existing projects, you can use migration tool: https://nx.dev/recipes/adopting-nx/migration-angular.

Note that you can't create an application using angular-cli because with starting with `nx` your `angular.json` file will just have links to `project.json` files in each /apps/appName or /libs/libName project